# How can I change image size?

Tags: graphics, alignment

I'm really new at this, not everyone in school use it but this profesor does, so Im good form now in everything except images, i don't understand how i can make them bigger.
This is how i do it so far

```
\begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,]{grantt.png}
\end{center}
```

[image]

So I want to make that bigger but keep it centered, i try to take out `\textwidth` and put width, and nothing happend, in other images works but it speads to the right, it not keep centered, im burnout

With png it goes to the right and with jpg nothing happen, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\begin{center}
  \makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{<image>}}
\end{center}
```

This will set the image in the middle of the text block at 20% wider than the text block width (`1.2\textwidth`). Adjust the width to suit your needs.